# Loop in JSON object and remove specific child

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json object from which i want to remove child having a key "errMsg".

```
input JSON : {"info":[{"errorMsg":"Unable to find Vendor ","c2v":"some text"},{"errorMsg":"Unable to find Vendor ","c2v":"Some text"},{"errorMsg":"Unable to find Vendor","c2v":" Some text"},{"id":"1038578481","ven":"DEMOMA","c2v":" Some text"}]}
```

result i want is the JSON should only have the child which doesn't have "errorMsg" in it.

```
output JSON i want : {"info":[{"id":"1038578481","ven":"DEMOMA","c2v":" Some text"}]}
```

code i used

```
jsonKeyInfo = stringToJson(form.response); 
for(var i in jsonKeyInfo.info){
            if(jsonKeyInfo.info[i].errorMsg){
                errMsg = jsonKeyInfo.info[i].errorMsg;
                jsonKeyInfo.info.splice(i,1);
                err++;
            //  delete jsonKeyInfo.info[i];
            }
        }
```

Not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this it will filter your array and will result your needed data as result

```
var jsonData = {"info":[{"errorMsg":"Unable to find Vendor ","c2v":"some text"},{"errorMsg":"Unable to find Vendor ","c2v":"Some text"},{"errorMsg":"Unable to find Vendor","c2v":" Some text"},{"id":"1038578481","ven":"DEMOMA","c2v":" Some text"}]};

var result = jsonData.info.filter(i=>!i.errorMsg)

console.log(result)
```

To assing it back use

jsonData.info = result;

try this in your console :) enjoy

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: I is not defined error, also can you confirm what this symbol mean i=>!i.errorMsg

Comment: they are known as arrow functions, for more info go through this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I is not defined error? can you please say that error in which part?

Answer (score 0):

```js
obj = {"info":[
  {"errorMsg":"Unable to find Vendor ","c2v":"some text"},
  {"errorMsg":"Unable to find Vendor ","c2v":"Some text"},
  {"errorMsg":"Unable to find Vendor","c2v":" Some text"},
  {"id":"1038578481","ven":"DEMOMA","c2v":" Some text"}
  ]}
  
  var changed = false;

obj.info = obj.info.filter((el)=> !( el.hasOwnProperty("errorMsg") && (changed = true) ));
console.log(obj);
console.log("Obj.info changed? " + changed);

changed = false;
obj2 = [
{"id":"1038578481","ven":"DEMOMA","c2v":" Some text"},
{"id":"1038578481","ven":"DEMOMA","c2v":" Some text"}
];

obj2.filter((el)=> !( el.hasOwnProperty("errorMsg") && (changed = true) ));
console.log("Obj2 changed? " + changed);
```

Comment: but i want output like {"info":[{"id":"1038578481","ven":"DEMOMA","c2v":" Some text"}]}

Comment: Then assign result back to `info` property (updated code)

Comment: Is it possible to set a flag as well "True" if result changes.